# Custom sorting for virtual ListView with ImageLIst

Tags: .net

[Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229643%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) explains sorting of a list without icons.

Icons are to be set in [ListView.LargeImageList property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.largeimagelist%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) as [ImageList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) instance. [ImageList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) can be mapped by keys, but I can't find a way to associate an image key with [ListViewItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) contained in the list.

Should user of [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) reorder [ImageList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) with icons on sorting?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ListViewItem.ImageKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.imagekey%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property to associate the item with an image.  If the order of the list view items changes due to sorting, the images for the items will display accordingly.